# How to send the date to the Server

Tags: android, datetime

I have two button one is for date_btn and another is for the time_btn ,when i hit date_btn i am opening datepicker dilog and when i am hitting the time_btn then i am opening the time_picker dialog .
i am saving date and time in the two string (i.e is dateString and another one is timeString).

What i need to do : the server is accepting this format of time

2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z

I am stucked how to send the dateString and timeString in this format "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss" to the server

Comment: can you just not append the strings?

Comment: server is not taking the appended string

Comment: you didn't even include your backend code here

Comment: Yes, @Beginner is right. At least post the server side of code. The accepting part atleast.

Comment: can U provide a sample of ur existing strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

to format your date.

please refer to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

First U have to concatinate ur strings together and convert into SimpleDateFormat   and see what format U have receive.
Then Do like this:

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   // Change "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"  according to ur farmat

   // Then for required output
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = sdf.parse(time);
    String formattedTime = output.format(d);
```

and save String formattedTime where U want.